# Rspec fakes method response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Let me quickly explain:

I'm testing `rails 4` model concern with `Rspec`. I made `shared_examples_for Uuidable` *(`Uuidable` is concern name)*

Concern is really short and easy to understand so I'm pasing code below:

```
module Uuidable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_create :generate_uuid
  end

  protected

  def generate_uuid
    self.uuid = loop do
      uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
      break uuid unless uuid_exists?
    end
  end

  private

  def uuid_exists?
     self.class.exists?(uuid: uuid)
  end

end
```

the problem is when I'm testing inside `RSpec`:

```
let(:model) { FactoryGirl.build(described_class) }
it 'should not generate same uuid' do
  SecureRandom.stub(:uuid).and_return("c640f32c-e21b-44ea-913e-7041fdb6de85", "c640f32c-e21b-44ea-913e-7041fdb6de85", "e93f0130-3a81-406f-8871-609d89ae0850")
  model.save
  expect(FactoryGirl.create(described_class).uuid).not_to eq(model.uuid)
end
```

Things gets really **funny** now:
Why? `Expect` fails. Reason? Oh well..

So to debug it I added `binding.pry` inside

```
  def generate_uuid
    self.uuid = loop do
      uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
      binding.pry
      break uuid unless uuid_exists?
    end
  end
```

let me share console output via screenshot:

[image: Console screenshot]

Let me quickly guide you through it:

First `=>` comes from `model.save`. First `SecureRandom.stub(:uuid)` was called. Everything is fine so I do `exit`

Second `=>` comes from `FactoryGirl.create(described_class)`. stubbed `SecureRandom.uuid` should return same uuid as it did in previous model and indeed it does *(call `[1]` and `[1]`).

What I expect to happen now: `uuid_exists?` return `true` so loop restarts and get 3rd stubbed `SecureRandom.uuid` and then save model. But in call `[2] uuid_exists?` we got... `false` ?!?! WHAAAT?

ok, maybe something went wrong with creating last model so I'll just manually call code from `uuid_exists?`.

WHAAAAAT?! it returns `true`!!!!. Couldn't believe so I redefined whole method in call `[4]`. It still returns `false`. Then few manual tests to ensure does last model exists and has uuid. it **DOES**

After call `[10]` test fails so it means it didn't go through `loop` again.

Can anyone please explain this strange behaviour?

#### Edit #1

When I changed `uuid_exists?` call in `unless` statement to `self.class.exists?(uuid: uuid)` it passes. I'm so **CONFUSED**

#### Edit #2

As requested I'm pasting text from console:

```
19:51:34 - INFO - Running: spec/models/review_spec.rb
*********.
From: /Users/filip/programming/service_matters/app/models/concerns/uuidable.rb @ line 13 Uuidable#generate_uuid:

    10: def generate_uuid
    11:   self.uuid = loop do
    12:     uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
 => 13:     binding.pry
    14:     break uuid unless uuid_exists?
    15:   end
    16: end

[1] pry(#<Review>)> uuid
=> "c640f32c-e21b-44ea-913e-7041fdb6de85"
[2] pry(#<Review>)> exit

From: /Users/filip/programming/service_matters/app/models/concerns/uuidable.rb @ line 13 Uuidable#generate_uuid:

    10: def generate_uuid
    11:   self.uuid = loop do
    12:     uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
 => 13:     binding.pry
    14:     break uuid unless uuid_exists?
    15:   end
    16: end

[1] pry(#<Review>)> uuid
=> "c640f32c-e21b-44ea-913e-7041fdb6de85"
[2] pry(#<Review>)> uuid_exists?
=> false
[3] pry(#<Review>)> self.class.exists?(uuid: uuid)
=> true
[4] pry(#<Review>)> def uuid_exists?
[4] pry(#<Review>)*   self.class.exists?(uuid: uuid)
[4] pry(#<Review>)* end
=> :uuid_exists?
[5] pry(#<Review>)> uuid_exists?
=> false
[6] pry(#<Review>)> self
=> #<Review id: nil, organization_id: 3, attitude: 1, feedback_action: "Refund", feedback_details: "Normandia SV2 didn't have AI module", approved: false, uuid: nil, feedback_date: "2014-08-18 17:51:58", created_at: "2014-08-28 17:51:58", updated_at: "2014-08-28 17:51:58", category_id: 3>
[7] pry(#<Review>)> self.uuid
=> nil
[8] pry(#<Review>)> Review.count
=> 1
[9] pry(#<Review>)> Review.first.uuid
=> "c640f32c-e21b-44ea-913e-7041fdb6de85"
[10] pry(#<Review>)> exit
F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `uuid_exists?` method checks for the presence of a row whose uuid is `self.uuid`, ie the value of your model's uuid attribute.

However your loop is only setting a local variable called uuid, so the attribute is always nil (since you only assign a value to it once the loop has completed), and your existance check does nothing. This unrelated to the fact that the method is stubbed (other than the fact that the stub is allowing you to test the case where a duplicate uuid was returned)

You could either pass the value to your `uuid_exists?` method as you suggest or do away with the local variable uuid altogether.